# How to pass params hash when rendering in other format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, parameters

I have such problem : I'm taking reports of current user and depends on dates, that are taken from inputs.

**BUT** I need to pass them into same page with xls extension, and now I'm getting errors such -

```
    undefined method each for nil:NilClass
```

So here is my controller:

```
def index

if params[:report] && params[:report][:start_date] && params[:report][:end_date]
  @start_date = params[:report][:start_date]
  @end_date = params[:report][:end_date]
  @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where(:created_at =>  @start_date.to_date..@end_date.to_date)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xls
  format.xml  { render :xml => @financial_reports }
   end
  end
end
```

**Here is my index.xls.erb**

```
          <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Amount</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Currency</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Created at</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  <% @financial_reports.each do |financial_report| %>
  <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= financial_report.amount %></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= financial_report.currency %></Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= financial_report.created_at %></Data></Cell>
  </Row>
   <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

**My LOG:**

```
  Started GET "/financial_reports.xls" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-09 16:52:30 +0300
   Processing by FinancialReportsController#index as XLS
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 67 LIMIT 1[0m
   Rendered financial_reports/index.xls.erb (0.0ms)
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms

 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
11:     <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Currency</Data></Cell>
12:     <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Created at</Data></Cell>
13:    </Row>
14:   <% @financial_reports.each do |financial_report| %>
15:   <Row>
16:     <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= financial_report.amount %></Data></Cell>
17:     <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= financial_report.currency %></Data></Cell>
app/views/financial_reports/index.xls.erb:14:in     `_app_views_financial_reports_index_xls_erb__791914298_25744200'


  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (10.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (30.0ms)
```

**EDIT: If I'm calling in controller**

```
   @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports
```

**It is working, but when I add WHERE condition - error appears .**

So how can I pass into xml view  ?

Comment: They will be passed into xls view just as html view, there may be other problems in the xls view, could you please post related code in the xls view?

Comment: @ZelluX , it is strange, because it is working when I write `@financial_reports = FinancialReport.all`

Answer (score 0):

create a view called 'app/views//index.xml.erb'

And stick your view in that (all the XML bit with the erb tags and stuff).

In your controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xls
  format.xml
end


current_user.financial_reports.where("financial_reports.created_at between ? and ?",params[:start_date].to_date,params[:end_date].to_date)
```

Comment: Your suggestion not working for me( I had .xls.erb file and it was working for case, that I mentioned in previous comment to ZelluX

Comment: You need to investigate which line is complaining about nil? then investigate why that object is nil when you dont expect it to be.

Comment: Aditya Sanghi, this line `<% @financial_reports.each do |financial_report| %>`. But I can't get why...

Comment: I found it. It is in where condition. Can you help ?

Comment: Sure you basically want to search for creates between 2 dates right?

Comment: Yes, I want to search between dates. Maybe I should create global variable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined method each for nil:NilClass
```

Means that you are dealing with a **nil object**, which in this case is `@financial_reports`. Why? Well maybe because there are no records in your database that meet your `WHERE` condition.

You should implement a check for nil objects and not render an xls in this case.

```
redirect_to <your_path_here> if @financial_reports.emtpy?
respond_to do |format|
....
```

The best way to debug this is either in the `rails console` or `development.log`. I prefer the `development.log` - it will show the SQL query being sent to the database and what is returned.

## Update - Try This

Change:

```
if params[:report] && params[:report][:start_date] && params[:report][:end_date]
  @start_date = params[:report][:start_date]
  @end_date = params[:report][:end_date]
  @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where(:created_at =>  @start_date.to_date..@end_date.to_date)
```

To:

```
if params[:start_date] && params[:end_date]
@financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where("financial_reports.created_at between ? and ?", params[:start_date].to_date, params[:end_date].to_date)
```

Comment: Just these params ` @start_date = params[:report][:start_date]
  @end_date = params[:report][:end_date] `
 didn't come to .xls page. Without that - it is working.

Comment: Those params would not naturally exist inside your .xls page. Your controller is using these variables to construct the `WHERE` SQL statement. Please paste the development log in your question to see what is really going on.

Comment: Brandon Jernigan, can you help me?